# rails how to fix:Expected 'production_sec' to be a URL string or a Hash. (ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::InvalidConfigurationError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used Rails7.0.4 to connect to multiple databases. Ruby3.2, database.yml, and model connect in this way.

```
default: &default

  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: xxx
  host: 172.17.0.1
  port: 3306

development: &development
  <<: *default
  database: art_bank_web

test: &test
  <<: *default
  database: art_bank_web_test

production: &production
  <<: *default
  database: art_bank_web

development_sec:
  <<: *default
  database: art_bank

test_sec:
  <<: *default
  database: art_bank_test

production_sec:
  <<: *default
  database: art_bank
```

```
class Artwork < ActiveRecord::Base
  #establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sec".to_sym
  #establish_connection "#{Rails.env}".to_sym
  #establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_sec"
  puts "#{Rails.env}_sec".to_sym.inspect
  puts "#{Rails.env}_sec".to_sym.to_s
  if Rails.env.test?
    establish_connection :test_sec
  else
    establish_connection 'development_sec'.to_sym
  end
```

However, when I started the production environment, I encountered this error.

```
:production_sec
production_sec
2023-06-27 01:12:44 +0000 Exiting!
/home/ubuntu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:217:in `build_db_config_from_string': '{ production => production_sec }' is not a valid configuration. Expected 'production_sec' to be a URL string or a Hash. (ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::InvalidConfigurationError)
    from /home/ubuntu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:203:in `build_db_config_from_raw_config'
    from /home/ubuntu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:129:in `resolve'
    from /home/ubuntu/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:353:in `resolve_config_for_connection'
```

May I ask why and how should I solve it?
I tried to modify the connection method of the model, but couldn't solve it

```
class Artwork < ActiveRecord::Base
  2   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_sec")
  3   #establish_connection :test_sec
  4   #ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  5   #  "mysql2://root:showmethemoney$$@172.17.0.1/art_bank_test"
  6   #)
  7   #self.table_name = "artworks"
```